# Sending HTTP POST requests one after another

Tags: java, rest, http, post, soapui

I am not sure where to start.

**Situation now**: We have a software that imports certain directories. To test this we have setup SOAPUI:

a) Using SOAPUI we can send POST request to our Web-based software. In this request we include a file address among other things.

b) Our software then responds to the PUT request telling us if it accepts the request or not. No further responses are received by SOAP UI in relation to the import PUT request sent.

c) Then our software starts to import the said directory/file.

**Problem**: The file/directory can sometimes be huge and it can take quite some time to import these files. This means someone has to manually check every few minutes if the previous import is complete and then send the next import request, this is a tedious job. **I want to automate this process.**

Our software does not send a response once the import is complete, additionally it cannot process more than 1 import requests at a time i.e. it will only accept any more import requests once the previous import is complete.

What I want want to do is make this process automated, i.e. send a POST request and then once the import is finished send the next import request.

**My Solution**: I have a general idea of how to achieve it i.e. my solution (piece of code) will send a POST request and after a pre-defined time slot (5 minutes) send the next request. If the response of the POST request is negative (meaning our software is still importing from the previous request) then my solution (piece of code) will wait another 5 minutes then send the POST request again. If the POST request is accepted by our software that means that the previous import is finished. This way I can automate this process and send as may POST requests as needed one after another.

**My need from this post**: I don't know which technologies to use. Is it possible with SOAP UI? Or maybe Java REST ASSURED framework might be my best solution? I am open to any other technology. Plus if you think this solution might not work please tell me or suggest another better solution.

I need help with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding possibility to send multiple requests in SoapUI - it can be done with Groovy script and creating a Test Suite, for example:

1. adding your request
2. after that adding a groovy script

[image: example test suite]

groovy script would contain your logic. I assume that request could be sent in a loop during some hours or while certain response message does not appear. Just as example a REST request with its JSON response parsed that is being run for a set time (of course in your case you would make http request and evaluate them according to possible response messages):

```
import net.sf.json.groovy.*
import groovy.time.*
import java.time.*

// send request and parse response
testRunner.runTestStepByName("Request_1")
def ResponseMessage = testRunner.testCase.testSteps.("Request_1").testRequest.response.contentAsString
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper ().parseText(ResponseMessage)
def response

// set cutoff time
def currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
def cutoffTime = LocalDateTime.now()

use(TimeCategory) {
    cutoffTime = cutoffTime.plusMinutes(2)
}

//looping until set time
while (currentTime < cutoffTime){
// make request
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("Request_1")
    response = jsonSlurper.message

    log.info "Response was: " + response

    sleep(300000)
    currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()

    }
```

However, in general SoapUI is rather as testing tool and your issue sounds more like a task for some job scheduling software